# Custom Button in JavaFX

Tags: java, wpf, javafx

Можно ли как в WPF заменить внутренний текст кнопки на контейнер?

Я перешла на javaFX с WPF. К хорошему привыкаешь быстро... В WPF у большинства элементов есть свойство Content, которое может хранить любой элемент, в том числе контейнер. Таким элементом является и Button.

Пыталась найти внутренности класса Button из JavaFX и остальных наследуемых им, но так и не нашла. В официальной документации нашла [статью](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm) для создания самодельного контроллера
Предполагаю, что только таким образом можно переопределить кнопку. Будет обидно, если это так, потому что придётся переопределять все встроенные анимации и события.

Уточнение: Если у кнопки будет контейнер, с ней можно делать всё что угодно. Одна задача с картинкой - это частный случай. Возможно, мне захочется добавить несколько по разному стилизованных Text-элементов, а между ними какую-нибудь линию. Такой гибкости, к большому сожалению, я не смогла найти. Посмотрите на картинку, надеюсь, что станет понятнее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @insolor, посмотрите уточнение.

Comment: Ребят, вы сейчас захейтили человека просто потому, что **не хотите сами** понимать вопрос. Вот что не понятного в том, что человек хочет вместо банального текста, внедрить в кнопку что-то другое, без разницы что...? Хотите примеров, ок, музыкальный плеер, где каждый трек (его название и прогресс проигрывания) находится на одной [кликабельной области](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nJZN.png); [список друзей](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqusP.png) с их аватаркой, статусом и т.д. Хватит хейтит и закрывать вопросы просто так!! В WPF подобное решается банальным `<Button>любой контент</Button>`.

Comment: Автор, а вам я советую всеж познавать C# и дальше, ибо у вас с ним был весьма хороший опыт, прогресс. Java как по мне, весьма консервативная, что не дает ей плюсов...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо за поддержку! Java пришлось изучать, т.к. требуется на работе. Поверхностно не позволяют принципы, нужно копать в глубь. За пол года с Java и JavaFX я поняла, что не у всех графических фреймворков есть общие подходы, WPF очень мощный фреймворк. И хотя на JavaFX можно делать красиво, приходится изощряться. Ну ещё один плюс, что в дальнейшем можно запускать программы на Linux, что может быть актуально.

Comment: @AB Вам нужно указать стиль дня кнопки, который будет использовать только graphic без текста (что бы не было проблем с отступами), а в поле graphic можно установить любую сложную Node, а не только картинку, так что вы внутри кнопки сможете сваять любую сложную структуру.  Я бы делал  свои extends Button для разных кейсов. Если вам нужно jvm решение, то я бы еще посмотрел на Compose Multiplatform for desktop, может с ним будет приятнее работать.

Comment: @Maxim, только вчера играла с SceneBuilder, и действительно, там появляется вложенный элемент graphics. В ближайшее время постараюсь добавить ответ.

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле, JavaFX не так уж и плох, как кажется на первый взгляд. Правда, именование некоторых методов вносит непонимания.

У Button есть метод setGraphic(Node a), который принимает любой Node, который является родительским для всех отображаемых элементов. Это означает, что можно вложить любой контейнер, а дальше уже куда фантазия унесёт.

[image]

Почему меня смутило название? Во-первых, в WPF все вложенные контейнеры - это content, но это только интуиция. Во-вторых, об этой функции почему-то сразу не рассказывают, когда рассказывают про устройство узлов контроллеров. В третьих, есть у них(контроллеров в JavaFX) свойство contentDisplayProperty, которое отвечает за позиционирование graphics внутри контейнера... Логика?! Зато отступы от  текста, который является содержимым по умолчанию, это graphicTextGapProperty... Тяжело...

[image]

Comment: Плюсую. Виноват, не стал разбираться, действительно такая возможность есть.

Comment: Да, а если еще css файл подключить, то может даже что-то симпатичное получиться.